# MySQL Table Indexes

Tags: mysql

Alright so I am trying to make Table 2 be linked with table 1 in a way.

This is the code for the table 1

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Name` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `table_1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `table_1`
  MODIFY `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

And this is the code for the table 2

```
CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hash` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `table_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `table_2`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now I want to link ID from table 1 with user_id from table 2, how do I do it?

So for example when I open up table 2 I want to see inside the user_id the ID from the table 1 etc..

Comment: Modified your title as it had nothing to do with PHP...

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` part of the foreign key creation process. Note however, that this will not auto-insert into `Table 2` when `Table 1` is updated. Instead, it will alter the `user_id` in `Table 2` if the corresponding user id in `Table 1` is modified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table_1 (ID);
```

Comment: Aha interesting, so when executing an insert query do I need to specify the ID or will it retrieve it automaticly?

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic It depends, you can manually retrieve the `ID` from `Table 1` and do a second query to insert into `Table 2` or you can look into _MySQL_ [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) to see how to do this internally within the db.

Comment: You have to specify user_id while inserting in table_2.

Comment: Yes you have to fetch id from table_1 to insert data according to id.

Comment: Aha hmm so whats the usage of the reference inside of it then? I am obligated to use it for something so preety much I dont know too much about it

Comment: The concept of foreign key and references is just to link tables with one another so as to prevent saving all data in one table. Read more at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-foreign-key.htm

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic FKs guarantee data integrity. So you want be able to insert a `user_id` into `table2` that does not exist in `table1`. Additionally the referencing row in `table2` can be updated and deleted automaticly (see `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` clauses). To determine the auto_increment ID after insert you should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.